# Recursively checking for values of a key

Tags: python

I am running into following error with below piece of code, basically below is what I am trying to do, below code works fine if there is only one value... if the values are more I get the error "too many values to unpack", how can I modify my code without changing the original goal...

1. if any of the values is a key with no values remove that line from the input
2. if any of the values is a key with values, for each value (which is key) recursively check for its values until there are none and remove the duplicate lines...a sample input and output is shown below:

   ```
   KEY    VALUES
   353311
   344670 
   332807 353314
   338169 334478
   334478 123456 34567
   123456 98670
   34567  11111  
   353314 353311
   348521 350166 350168 350169 350170 
   350166 348521
   350168 348521
   350169 348521
   350170 348521

   EXPECTED OUTPUT
   344670
   332807 353314 353311
   338169 334478 123456 34567 98670 11111
   348521 350166 350168 350169 350170
   ```

Code:-

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def main ():
    with open('gerrit_dependencylist.txt') as f:
        dic = OrderedDict()
        seen = set()
        for line in f:
            #print dic,line
            spl = line.split()
            print "SPL"
            print spl
            if len(spl) == 1:
                key = spl[0]
                v = ''
            else:
                print "LINE"
                print line
                key, v = spl
            if v in dic and dic[v] == [""]:
                del dic[v]
            for k1,v1 in dic.items():
                if key in v1:
                    dic[k1].append(v)
                    break
            else:
                dic[key] = [v]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

OUTPUT:-

```
LINE
332807 353314

LINE
338169 334478

LINE
334478 123456 34567

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tesst.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "tesst.py", line 18, in main
    key, v = spl
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the line has 3 items

334478 123456 34567

so

```
spl = ["334478", "123456", "34567"]
```

you are trying to unpack them into two

```
key, v
```

perhaps you want

```
key = spl[0]
v = spl[1:]
```

You can also write that on one line

```
key, v = spl[0], spl[1:]
```

Comment: @gnibber - if I use that ..i get an error     if v in dic and dic[v] == [""]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user2125827, because you can't just ask a dictionary if it contains a particular value. `in dic` works for the keys. I think you mean to iterate over v to get the individual values to look up.

Comment: @user2125827 Use `for value in v: if value == desired: ...`

Comment: @user2125827 gnibbler has explained how to solve your immediate problem, if you have another then I suggest you ask a separate follow up question.